# What happens when Linux Can't Find a Driver for a USB device?

Tags: linux, usb

In this case, according to the article: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6396 there are several 'handlers' for specific USB devices (ie: keyboard, mice).

If a USB device has no such driver that is loaded, does this mean that the handler used is an "Event Handler" (rather than a specific handler such as joystick or keyboard?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact device. If it's a HID device, it's added to the event subsystem. If it's a UMS device, it's added to usb-storage. At the very worst, apps can frob the low-level USB interface with libusb if there's absolutely no driver for the device's class.